# three.js object starting animation/game loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

Im using angularJS and Three.js for my front end.

i have created my three.js object like this:

```
var ThreeObject = (function() {
//constructor
function ThreeObject() {}

ThreeObject.prototype.init = functio init (){
//init scene,renderer,....
};

ThreeObject.prototype.update = function update(){
//update various objects attatched to scene
};

ThreeObject.prototype.draw = function draw(){
this.renderer.render(this.scene,this.camera);
};

return ThreeObject;
})();
```

in my angular controller I am calling:

```
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {

    var foo = new ThreeObject(800,600);
    foo.init(document.getElementById('container'));

    function loop() {
        foo.update();
        foo.draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }]);
```

Since angular promotes MVC my first response was to encapsulate all the three.js behavior into a model. What i am unsure of thou is if this is a correct approach?

Would it be better to create a directive which handels the loop? Would this have any advantages to the approach that im using?

Comment: Is Angular even necessary in this project? It doesn't seem like it is doing anything for you.

Comment: Well i would like to use it. The project consists of more than posted, but that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Well in that case, your approach seems correct. You would not place it in a directive. You would just want to make sure that if you create another controller, it is a child of this one, so that your scope is not destroyed.

Comment: ok, sounds good. thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I've made with AngularJS and THREEjs using a factory instead of a directive.  I'm using a render loop in this example which is internal to the factory.

http://blog.tempt3d.com/2014/02/angularjs-threejs-servicefactory.html

Hope this helps.